# Best way in Javascript to check if string is inside an huge txt/csv?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, csv, lookup

My real world problem is: users of my mobile app type their city and I have to make sure it really exists, and that it is correctly written (caseinsensitive, so these are correct: New York, NEW york, new york. This is not correct: newyork)
There are online apis that work quite well (Google Geocode API for example) but:

1. After a very little amount of requests, you have to pay (2.500/day right now)
2. Users must be connected to the internet

That's why I tought that an offline-local solution would be better. There are many websites (like [Maxmind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities)) where you can download a list containing every city in the world. I could embed this huge txt/csv right inside my application and do a string search locally (it's a big file, ok, but not that big. It's just a onetime download of something like 30-40MB of uncompressed .txt)
I'm trying to avoid jQuery at all costs and I don't want to use any PHP/MySQL solutions (even if fulltext indexes could be handy), that's why I'm trying to do all this just using javascript.
Given a string as input, let's say "city3", what's the best/fastest way to check if it's inside an (external) huge list like:

- city1,
- city2,
- city3,
- city4,
- [...]

After solving this (big) problem: if there are no exact matches, is there a way to search for the correct city without freezing the device for 10 minutes? 
In the example before, lets say the user types "cit y3" or "cyty3" or "cìty3": can any js function tell him that he might be looking for "city3"? Is this kind of search too slow in this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: so you're worried about speed, but you want to dump 40+meg of text into your webpage and search it repeatedly?

Comment: Host it as a web service yourself, then don't charge yourself.

Comment: A mobile device is not a database. Performing a fuzzy search on a large set is nothing trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is an issue then I would recommend loading the data into a JavaScript object and performing an in-memory search rather than repeatedly scanning a big blob of text in a file.

Try formatting the data into JSON with the city names as keys, that will give you good search performance.

Answer (score 0):

A Workaround is creating a Database either SQL either noSQL, and Query this database through your JavaScript Code, using jquery Json functions.

Using a SQL Database ideal would be either [**MySQL**](http://www.mysql.com/) either [**MariaDB**](https://mariadb.org/) *An enhanced, drop-in replacement for MySQL.*

In this solution you will probably need a Backend such as **[PHP](http://php.net/)** to fetch the data from your Database convert them to JSON Format, and then get them through your JavaScript using jQUery Library , with the [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function

---

Using a noSQL Database ideal would be **[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)**.

In this solution you can fetch your data directly from javascript, also with the $.getJSON function.

Example for MongoDB Provided [Here](http://etoxin.net/blog/2013/07/09/mongodb-and-jquery-in-10-minutes/)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use database i think you can do this:

-first , instead use one big file split it into several files. (you can write a script for this and use it just one time for split the big file). in each file put cities that starts with (example) aa , second file cityes that starts with ab.

-then for each city check first letters and then search inside that file.
For example if you need to search for  city "Ahmedabad" it will search only in the files with cities that starts with Ah. Probably this is not the best solution ,at the end you got 421 file instead 1 , but reasearch will be faster.

Comment: Even if I have a smaller .txt file, what's the fastest way to search for a string inside of it?

Comment: if you only need to know if string exists , i would use substring().